# using printf for multiple formats

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I have a question on how to use printf for multiple formats. I want something like this, where everything inside printf is spaced out evenly:

```
i     i     i     i     i
```

and this is how I used printf:

```
// display headers
    System.out.printf("", "%15s", "%15s", "%15s", "%15s", "Car Type", 
            "Starting Miles", "Ending Miles", "Distance/Gallon", 
            "Gallons/Distance", "Miles/Gallon");
```

when I executed my program, the above wouldn't show up at all, I just go this:

```
run:
Gas & Mileage Calculations

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Check my answer to see, why your try prints out nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the formats:

```
System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%15s", "header 1", "header 2", ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you use `printf()` is wrong.

It's first parameter is `String format`, which will be the formatting string, which implements all further arguments.

Example:

```
String name = "Chris";
int age = 25;
System.out.printf("%s = %d", name, age);
```

This will print out "Chris = 25", because `%s` is converted into the variable `name` and `%d` into variable `age`. Check the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for more information.